# What is the best way to handle multiple countries, languages, and mobile/dekstop views?

Tags: multistore, localisation, rwd, multicurrency

I have site that will need to front stores for two countries (US, MX). Both countries need to be available in en_US and es_MX languages. There is no difference between the product offerings for the countries, only the currency and translation of the product data, including images.

The theme will be responsive but there are certain blocks the are only used in the "large" or "small" screen views so something RESS like is required.  There are also certain pieces of content coming from the Catalog that will need to be different for "small" and "large" screens (in addition to language) for example "category" banner images that need to be different between "small" and "large" because of the aspect ratio.

I read [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6775/is-it-the-best-strategy-to-create-a-store-for-each-country-i-serve) in addition to several articles and it seems like I'll need to do the second option from the SO question:

```
Website:    country
Store:      small/large
Store View: translations
```

Will this accommodate all my requirements? Are there any additional drawbacks other than those listed in the [referenced SO q/a](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6775/is-it-the-best-strategy-to-create-a-store-for-each-country-i-serve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create different stores for mobile and desktop views. You can just create different themes within your package and use them with design exceptions based on browser user agent.

The rest is correct. You can use either websites or stores abstraction for local stores and store views for translations.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to build a website that will have two languages (en_US and es_MX) and want two different themes for desktop and mobile users.

The proper way to do this is to create one website, one store and two storeviews, then set a mobile theme.

I assume from what you said that you already now how to create the two store views and set the languages.

Let's  say you have created the two themes and are placed in their respective directories

`MY_PACKAGE/DESKTOP_THEME` for your desktop theme and

`MY_PACKAGE/MOBILE_THEME` for you mobile theme

To set a mobile theme

- login to our backend
- navigate to System-> Configuration
- Find the 'Design' tab.
- In the 'Package' section type MY_PACKAGE in Current Package Name
- In the 'Themes' section type DESKTOP_THEME in each of the fields.

You have set up a desktop theme but right now mobile devices don't show anything different. So ..

- In the 'Themes' section, click 'Add Exception for each of the Templates,Skin,Layout.
  In each box that appears input

  Matched Expression :: iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini

  value :: MOBILE_THEME

Now (most of) the mobile devices will be fed with your mobile theme

NOTE:: It is good practice, if you create a new package to name your DEKTOP_THEME default, so your mobile theme won't default to base